# Typescript compile with imports

Tags: javascript, typescript

So I have two files: `a.ts` and `b.ts`. `b` exports something for `a` to use. The TypeScript compiler handles this fine, but refuses to create valid output for a browser. Example:

```js
import { test } from "./b";

console.log(test);
```

`b.ts`

```js
export const test = "quest";
```

and now I try compiling it:

```sh
$ tsc --lib dom,es2018 --target ES2018 --out test.js a.ts b.ts
b.ts:1:1 - error TS6131: Cannot compile modules using option 'out' unless the '--module' flag is 'amd' or 'system'.

1 export const test = "quest";
  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~


Found 1 error.
```

hm, weird. Okay, let's try using `--module`. If I use `amd` a browser that loads `test.js` will tell me: `ReferenceError: define is not defined`. If I try `system` it says: `ReferenceError: System is not defined`.

Okay, that's not working. Let's try without setting a single output file with `--out`. That gives me:

```
SyntaxError: import declarations may only appear at top level of a module a.js:1
SyntaxError: export declarations may only appear at top level of a module b.js:1
```

So based on this, it seems like my only options for using typescript are:

- Put all code in a single file
- Use an external library like require.js or webpack
- Learn what a module is and if/how it can be used in a browser

Or am I missing something? How do I compile Typescript using imports without adding libraries/modules ?

TypeScript version: 3.8.3

Comment: Have you tried to declare the variable, and then export it? `const test = ""; export test;`

Comment: The export line then gives me "declaration or statement expected" as a compilation error

Answer (score -2):

Syntax error

please correct this

export const test = "quest";

to

export test = "quest";

No need to add any const here while exporting

Comment: No, what I'm doing now doesn't have any compiler errors. If I do as you suggest I get a compiler error "Declaration or statement  expected".

Comment: module.exports = test  try this

Comment: `Cannot find name 'module'`